# Porting Liquibase changelog to different RDBMS

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

We have a couple of Spring Boot based services that make use of Liquibase as schema migration tool (based on the integration provided by Spring Boot).

For historical reasons, the changelogs are currently not database-agnostic, i.e., they make use of Oracle-specific data types. However, we'd like to switch from Oracle to PostgreSQL in the near future. To make the existing changelog compatible with PostgreSQL, it will have to be modified invalidating the existing contents of the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and services will probably refuse to start.

What would be a suitable approach to tackle this migration? Throw away the changelog history, rebuild the schema from scratch using the modified changelog and then migrate the data? Are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your changesets to become valid for oracle and postgresql and then provide valid checksum inside them (maybe there is also method to create that).

```xml
<changeSet id="id" author="author">
    <validCheckSum></validCheckSum>
    ...
</changeSet>
```

When you run the liquibase next time it checks the checksum against valid checksum and if it's ok then it wouldn't fail.

Sometimes you will see that it's better to use some types from specific database (for example text vs varchar2) so you can parameterize those. And this is not limited to types only.

```xml
<property dbms="postgres" name="texttype" value="TEXT"/>
<property dbms="oracle" name="texttype" value="VARCHAR2"/>

<changeSet id="id" author="author">
    <createTable tableName="testtable">
        <column name="test" type="${texttype}" />
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

And from previous example you can see that there is usage of attribute `dbms` in some liquibase elements. Sometimes it's better to write something with specific dbms syntax instead of using some abstraction.